# Writing a script that runs in repo root folder and updates all subrepos

Tags: mercurial

I've had the following script that worked perfectly but relied on the `onsub` extension to update the main repo and all subrepos:

```
hg pull --rebase
hg onsub -t hg "hg pull --update"
hg onsub -t hg "hg update"
```

Since 2017, onsub is no longer available: https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/OnsubExtension

How can I perform the same task now without hard-coding the list of subrepos?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the batch script I came up with so far, but it's Windows-only, obviously, while the `onsub` solution was portable. Also, it doesn't check whether a detected nested repository is actually listed in `.hgsub`.

```
hg pull --rebase
hg update

@echo off
FOR /D %%s IN (*) DO (
    IF EXIST %%s\.hg\ (
        pushd %%s
        @echo on
        hg pull --rebase
        hg update
        @echo off
        popd
    )
)
@echo on
```